# Can't get the value from a jagged array in the place I want but I get it on an other place

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int rowIn = 0;
    int[][] parts2 = new int[15][];//jagged output Array

    //The txt-file has 1 number in the top line and every next line has 1 number more, all seperated by a space
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("inputProblem18.txt"))//put the txt file in the same directory as the exe file
    {
        int columnIn = 0;

        string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

        int[] nums = new int[parts.Length];

        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            nums[columnIn] = Int32.Parse(parts[columnIn]);
            parts2[rowIn] = nums;//fill the jagged output array
            Console.Write(nums[columnIn] + " ");
            columnIn++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        rowIn++;
    }

    for (int rowOut = 14; rowOut >= 1; rowOut--)
    {
        for (int columnOut = rowOut-1; columnOut >= 0; columnOut--)
        {
            parts2[rowOut - 1][columnOut] += Math.Max(parts2[rowOut][columnOut], parts2[rowOut][columnOut + 1]);
            Console.Write(parts2[rowOut - 1][columnOut] + " ");//I got the answere here
            Console.Write(rowOut - 1 + " " + columnOut + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // The line below is causing me the error
    Console.WriteLine("The greatest sum from top to bottom is: {1}", parts2[0][0]);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm working on Project Euler, a nice site with nice programming problems. I used a jagged array for the first time in my live :-) so I think I don't understand it quit well.

I want to display the answer, the value of a jagged array at position [0][0] at the end of the file but I got an error and I don't know why. In the for loop I got the right value.

This is the error message :

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you tell us the exact error you're getting, and where?

Comment: I got a message that the index must be 0 minimum to length maximum. I thought it was the index from the array but is was the index of the arguments in the Console.WriteLine. See the answer.

Comment: Please edit the *exact* error message into the question, to improve the question itself. I'd also uncomment the line that fails from your code - the code you include in the question should demonstrate the problem you're reporting.

Comment: @JonSkeet as long as we got the informations about his problem, I edited the question. I think this question could still be improved

Comment: @Cid: The reason I'd hoped that the OP would do it was to help them get in the habit of providing the information in the question. I'm not suggesting a roll-back, but there's value in a user doing things themselves. (Having said that, I reformatted the code myself in revision 2...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `{1}` to display `parts2[0][0]`. Since this is the first variable, this should be `{0}`, not 1. The argument list can be considered as an array and starts at index 0.

Change this :

```
//      Notice this ----------------------------------------v
Console.WriteLine("The greatest sum from top to bottom is: {1}", parts2[0][0]);
// Boom !
// Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal
// to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

To this :

```
//      Notice this ----------------------------------------v
Console.WriteLine("The greatest sum from top to bottom is: {0}", parts2[0][0]);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I looked for hours and I didn't see it. :-)